# Minecraft command: villager trading adventure mode items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone tell me why this command doesn't work?

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:Jerry,CustomNameVisible:0,NoAI:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:lever,Count:1,Damage:#},buyB:{id:cooked_porkchop,Count:30,Damage:#},sell:{id:lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_ore"]},Count:1,Damage:#}}]}}
```

the villager isn't selling adventure mode item

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? It's hard to say why something doesn't work if we don't know what the goal is

Comment: villager not offering lever. everything else works,

Answer (score 2):

Your `id` value for the `sell` compound is incorrect. It appears you may have copy/pasted a `/give` command into NBT data. The entire line "lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_ore"]}" is seen as the item's ID, which is invalid.

Any tags that are not the root `id`, `Damage`, `Count`, and `Slot` must be placed within a single `tag` compound.

Fixed command:

```
/summon Villager ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:Jerry,CustomNameVisible:0,NoAI:1,Offers:{Recipes:[{maxUses:10,buy:{id:lever,Count:1,Damage:0},buyB:{id:cooked_porkchop,Count:30,Damage:0},sell:{id:lever,Count:1,Damage:0,tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_ore"]}}}]}}
```